# Why does rebinding the __setitem__ method of a UserDict instance have no effect on updates to the object?

Tags: python

The following code does not behave as I expected with Python 3.4.2:

```
>>> from collections import UserDict
>>> class freezable_dict(UserDict):
    def freeze(self):
        def __setitem__(*args):   # (self, *args) behaves the same
            '''custom __setitem__'''
            raise TypeError
        self.__setitem__ = __setitem__

>>> f=freezable_dict()
>>> f[0]=42
>>> help(f.__setitem__)
Help on method __setitem__ in module collections:

__setitem__(key, item) method of __main__.freezable_dict instance

>>> f.freeze()
>>> help(f.__setitem__)
Help on function __setitem__ in module __main__:

__setitem__(*args)
    custom __setitem__

>>> f[1]=42
>>> f
{0: 42, 1: 42}
>>>
```

After calling the `freeze` method, `help(f.__setitem__)` shows the expected docstring. But, the function I rebound the special method name to is not what is called by `f[1]=42`. I would have expected the attempt to add a new item to `f` after invoking `f.freeze` to raise a TypeError. Why doesn't it?

(I'm actually interested here in why my code doesn't work as I expected. But, the motivation is that I want to populate a dict-like thing and, once it is initially populated, lock it down against further changes. Had my code here worked, I would have gone on to have the `freeze` method also rebind `__delitem__`.)